# Conditional compilation for class properties based on consuming project

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

Is it possible to use the #if compiler directives to omit properties on a class?

I have two projects consuming the shared project and I want to add some properties to a shared class that I don't want the other one to see.

I've tried adding a Conditional Compilation Symbol in on of the projects e.g. MYSYMBOL

and then doing this in my class:

```
#if MYSYMBOL

public string MySpecialProperty { get; set; }

#endif
```

It compiles but neither project can see the MySpecialProperty whereas obviously I would be hoping for the project with the MYSYMBOL defined to be able to access this property...

Comment: Why don't you inherit from this class in your second project to add the two new properties? Your base project cannot make use of these two properties internally very effectively if they are conditional. The need to make them conditional seems like a design-smell.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth thanks for your suggestion but I'm just interested to know if what I've asked is possible :-)

Answer (score 0):

`MYSYMBOL` must be defined in the compiling project in order to make the property visible. Thus, if you have a common library project, you can define it there or not. Therefore, the compiled library will always either contain the property or not, regardless of which consuming project you use the library in.

If you want a different behavior, you have to compile the class in both consuming projects. You can add the same source file to both projects and compile it with different definitions.